# Build SwiftUI "Hello World" on MacOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

SwiftUI "Hello World" works on iOS, but NOT MacOS.

Trying to build a simple "Hello World" SwiftUI example to see how it works on Mac, but I am getting an empty black screen app.

I am using Xcode 11
MacOS target is checked
MacOS version 10.15 Beta (19A471t)

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.constant(true)/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Toggle"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            }
            Stepper(value: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.constant(4)/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, in: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1...10/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Text("Stepper")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
            }
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Could you please fix the source code? There's some gibberish in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now OK with [Xcode 11 beta 2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_2_release_notes):

> Xcode 11 beta supports development with SwiftUI.

Note that the skeleton app created by Beta 1 (created from the New project menu) won't work. You need to use the one created by Beta 2.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue, mentioned in [Xcode 11 Beta Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes):

> Xcode 11 beta doesn’t support working with SwiftUI in a project
>   configured to use UIKit for Mac.

So the only option we have is to wait until the next Xcode 11 beta release.

---

Update: This works with Xcode 11.0 beta 2.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I've been wondering this myself too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mo Reza!

Have you tried previewing SwiftUI MacOS in Xcode Preview?

I tried following code but didn't work also:

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
            .previewDevice("Mac")
            ContentView()
                .previewDevice("iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)"

Comment: @AlexandreLordelo The iPad preview works fine, but the mac won't appear. Maybe another string is needed for it or it is not yet supported in preview!

Comment: @AlexandreLordelo is the preview also fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It's work well on Xcode 11 beta 2 & macOS 10.15 beta2 .

[image]

Comment: Haven’t been able to test mac preview yet. Do you know the code for it?

Comment: @AlexandreLordelo Xcode 11 beta 2 & macOS 10.15 beta2, it's enough

Comment: thanks! Im assuming you are using Mac as a build target? How about defining on Debug code, so you could preview both iOS and MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

While it is a known issue that Xcode 11 beta 1 is missing support, you can enable it by changing the scene setup in your SceneDelegate `willConnectTo` method:

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(UIKitForMac)
    let windowScene = UIWindowScene(session: session, connectionOptions: connectionOptions)
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
#else
    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
#endif
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView:
      ContentView()
        .environmentObject(TimersStore.shared)
        .environmentObject(SettingsStore.shared)
    )
```

I have this code guarded because for some reason, if you use UIWindowScene on iOS/iPadOS targets it causes the keyboard to no longer appear & text entry doesn't work. This is also true of the app running on macOS, but you can at least check out the way your app looks / runs.

Answer (score 0):

This is now super easy in SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, Mac!")
    }
    #else
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, iOS!")
    }
    #endif
}
```

Make sure you checked "Mac" in the Deployment Info targets.